# Is there a more efficient way of writing this stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to sql, is there a better way or more efficient way of writing the following query I wrote.  I am trying to pull all the recipe categories by recipe id, if their is a record for that cateogy for the recipe id in the junction table, it should return true, otherwise return false.

here is a screenshot of the expected output for one recipe id, you see how some have IsTagged True, others are False

[image: ScreenShot]

```
SELECT Name AS TagName, Id AS TagID, 'false' AS IsTagged
FROM dbo.Category

EXCEPT 

SELECT category.Name AS TagName, category.ID AS TagID, 'false' AS IsTagged
FROM dbo.Category AS category
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RecipeCategoryJunction AS junction
    ON junction.CategoryID = category.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Recipes AS recipe
    ON recipe.Id = junction.RecipeId
WHERE recipe.Id = 1019

UNION

SELECT category.Name AS TagName, category.ID AS TagID, 'true' AS IsTagged
FROM dbo.Category AS category
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RecipeCategoryJunction AS junction
    ON junction.CategoryID = category.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Recipes AS recipe
    ON recipe.Id = junction.RecipeId
WHERE recipe.Id = 1019
```

Comment: Why are you using `'single quotes'` for both `'string literals'` and `'column aliases'`? Don't you find that confusing and hard to read?

Comment: I don't find it hard to read

Comment: That's great. How about your readers? How about the poor person who has to inherit your code? I find it very hard to read and reverse engineer, and I really doubt I'm alone. You don't need delimiters on those column aliases at all. Also, table aliases like a, b, and c are silly if they have no relevance to the table. `Category` = `a` and `Recipes` = `c`? Really?

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize it was hard to read, it made sense in my head.  I updated the code to use proper aliases

Comment: Anyway you don't need all this union and except stuff - a simple left join will do. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03a85/1

Comment: Does this mean the question is answered? @AaronBertrand Apparently, I can't flag your comment as 'should be an answer'. :)

Comment: this is the answer, I can't flag it as the answer though because it's in the comments

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with a left join alone.

```
SELECT C.Name AS TagName, 
       C.Id AS TagID,
       (CASE WHEN junction.CategoryID is NULL then 'False' Else 'True') AS IsTagged
FROM dbo.Category C
LEFT JOIN dbo.RecipeCategoryJunction AS junction
    ON junction.CategoryID = category.Id
    junction.RecipeId =1019
```